# How can I match values from two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP, how can I match subscribers to users with these two arrays?

**$subscribers**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_id] => 1
            [email] => name@example.com
        )

)
```

**$users**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [user_email] => name@example.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [user_email] => name2@example.com
        )
```

I thought this would do it...

```
<?php
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    if ( in_array( 'name@example.com', $subscribers ) ) {
        echo 'Matched user';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
        if ($user->user_email === $subscriber->email) {
            echo 'Matched user';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized why mine isn't working. `$subscribers` is an array. `$users` is an object. Have a tweak to make that work?

Comment: From what you pasted, `$users` is an array of objects, as is `$subscribers`.  If it's not, then you need to fix your question to reflect the real value stored in that variable.

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out that it was just a matter of case differences! `strltolower( $user->user_email )` fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: **Do not use `strtolower()` on email addresses.** The mailbox name *is* case-sensitive according to the RFC.  In other words, in "test@example.com", "test" is case-sensitive.  ("example.com" is not.)  "test@example.com" and "Test@example.com" are *different mailboxes.*